# Correlation between 2 python lists

Tags: python, time, statistics, correlation

I would like to correlate 2 lists like this:

```
a=[1337687805.49052, 1337687808.560519, 1337687813.06552, 1337687814.602522,
   1337687817.16352, 1337687823.836521, 1337687831.942522, 1337687837.931519, 
   1337687839.760519, 1337694258.54652, 1337709019.39452, 1337712024.05452, 
   1337714200.05952, 1337714903.08152, 1337721205.97952, 1337721207.05052, 
   1337723273.93052]

b=[1337687803.533521, 1337688287.44452, 1337689866.760521, 1337689866.76352,
   1337690758.328521, 1337691231.61552, 1337691261.578519, 1337691261.68752,
   1337691362.20652, 1337691362.51652, 1337691366.431521, 1337691369.55252,
   1337691369.992521, 1337691387.000521, 1337691391.50552, 1337691406.192519, 
   1337691407.79952, 1337691411.74352, 1337691420.308521, 1337691422.035521, 
   1337691426.60752, 1337691426.753521, 1337691431.44952, 1337691437.87152, 
   1337691438.66452, 1337691448.45452, 1337691450.15852, 1337691451.49252, 
   1337691454.335519, 1337691459.87152, 1337691461.01652, 1337691480.819519, 
   1337691482.980521, 1337691484.914522, 1337691500.15652, 1337691514.32752]
```

a and b contains the epoch time of some events, so I need the correlation between a and b, do some significant graphs, maybe the correlation coefficient is useful too.
The goal is to compare a lot of vectors a,b,c,d,... with different timestamps in order to know if they had a similar behavior.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should consider [`scipy.spatial.distance`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/spatial.distance.html).

You can get correlation using `scipy.spatial.distance.euclidean()` or [`scipy.spatial.distance.correlation()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.correlation.html?highlight=correlation#scipy.spatial.distance.correlation)

http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/search.html?q=correlation&check_keywords=yes&area=default

Comment: thanks for answering so fast!
it doesn't work, maybe because all lists have different sizes. is it possible?

Comment: no. the list have to be of the same size. or else, you can give each element separately. eg. correlation(l1[0],l2[0])